If $A$ is a discrete set, compact convergence on $\Omega \setminus A$ implies compact convergence on $\Omega$
Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{C}$ be a domain, $\{f_n\}$, $f_n:\Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ a sequence of holomorphic functions on $\Omega$ and let $A\subset \Omega$ be a discrete set. If $\{f_n\}$ converges compactly on $\Omega\setminus A$, then $\{f_n\}$ converges compactly on $\Omega$.
My attempt:
Let $K\subset \Omega$ be a compact set. We have to show that $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly on $K$. To this end, I want to define a compact subset of $\Omega\setminus A$ related to $K$. However, I couldn't be able to this. I have notice that being $A$ a discrete set and $K$ compact, then $K\cap A$ is finite, but I don't know if this helps in the proof.

Hint: Compact convergence is equivalent to uniform convergence in a neighborhood of every point. Use Morera's theorem to argue that the limit is holomorphic in $\Omega$, then use Cauchy's integral formula to get uniform convergence.

Thanks for your hint. However, I don't understand when you said, "to argue that the limit is holomorphic in $\Omega$." Which limit? I can't see neither when the fact that $A$ is discrete is used in the proof. Could you please explain this a little bit? Thanks again.

@Gerschgorin: Well, since there's only convergence in $\Omega\setminus A$, the limit function is only defined there. You want to use Morera to argue the limit is in fact analytic in $\Omega$. To guarantee you can use this theorem you need $A$ discrete since you don't want points in $A$ landing in the curve you're integrating on.
